# Do conventional ovens heat by thermal conduction or radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

I am curious which energy transfer mechanism dominates in a [conventional oven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oven), [thermal conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction) or [thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation)?

A naive guess would be that early on, when the food is still cold, the heat transfer rate would be higher for radiative than conductive transfer due to the dependence on $\Delta T^{4}$ for the former compared to $\Delta T$ for the latter.  However, it is not clear to me if the oven elements/burners heat the air and the air transfers the heat through conduction or the oven walls radiate in infrared and heat through radiative transfer.

If we are heating a solid food (e.g., beef/meat) and we assume the air inside the oven is a constant, uniform temperature then we only have conductive and radiative heat processes, correct?  Meaning, I need not worry about convection.

If these assumptions are correct, then what heat transfer mechanism will dominate and why?

Comment: Another answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/334251/226902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the oven walls radiate like perfect [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) radiators and the air inside the oven is uniform throughout (ignore the thin layer near the cooler meat).  Assume I want to cook a [prime rib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_rib_roast) (chosen because it can be bought in a cut that has a cylindrical shape), which is just beef and fat.  I can look up the [thermal emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity) and [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity) of beef to find:

- $\epsilon$ ~ 0.74–0.78, depending on fat content; and
- $\kappa$ ~ 0.504–0.561 W m<sup>-1</sup> K<sup>-1</sup>, depending on fat content.

We know the heat transfer rate for radiative heating can be approximated by:
$$
\dot{Q}_{rad} \approx \sigma \ \epsilon \ A \ \left( T_{oven}^{4} - T_{beef}^{4} \right) \tag{1}
$$
where $\sigma$ is the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant), $\epsilon$ is the radiative emissivity, $A$ is the surface area of the absorber, and $T_{j}$ is the temperature of the j<sup>th</sup> object.

Similarly, we know heat transfer rate for conductive heating can be approximated by:
$$
\dot{Q}_{con} \approx \frac{ \kappa \ A \left( T_{oven} - T_{beef} \right) }{ L } \tag{2}
$$
where $\kappa$ is the thermal conductivity, $A$ is the surface area of the absorber, $L$ is the thickness of the absorber, and again $T_{j}$ is the temperature of the j<sup>th</sup> object.

Let's assume we buy a prime rib that is ~1.5 ft (~0.46 m) in length and ~5 in (~0.13 m) in diameter and approximate it as a cylinder.  Then the absorbing surface area and thickness would be $A$ ~ 0.42 m<sup>2</sup> and $L$ ~ 0.13 m.  If the meat starts at 32 <sup>o</sup>F (273.15 K) and the oven is at 350 <sup>o</sup>F (449.82 K), the rates from Equations 1 and 2 when the meat first enters the oven are:

- $\dot{Q}_{rad}$ ~ 630–664 W; and
- $\dot{Q}_{con}$ ~ 297–331 W.

Obviously this is a function of time since the $\Delta T$ will change with time.  The constant factors for each are $\sim 1.8 \times 10^{-8}$ W K<sup>-4</sup> for $\dot{Q}_{rad}$ and $\sim 1.8$ W K<sup>-1</sup> for $\dot{Q}_{con}$.  One can go ahead and plot the transfer rates (see figure below) and find that radiative transfer always dominates.

[image: Radiative vs. Conductive Heating Rates]

> If these assumptions are correct, then what heat transfer mechanism will dominate and why?

So if we can truly ignore convection, then it appears that radiation dominates over conduction.

Comment: That does assume the meat is effectively in contact with the oven walls - by ignoring the low heat capacity of air. A better model of the oven would be to assume k for air with a length of the half the width of the oven

Comment: @MartinBeckett - I knew there was something I was missing but was not sure whether the air would matter that much.  I partly posted the question and answer because I have seen so many articles that argue for one or the other but none of them seem very definitive/conclusive.  In many of the articles the dominant heating process is stated anecdotally but not actually shown to be true.  So I thought perhaps I could provoke a better, more quantitative answer.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Most convincing articles I'd seen gave radiation as the larger heat source in a conventional oven.  Quite honestly though, I think choosing to use $T_{oven}$ for conduction works in your favour here.  I can't imagine that adding the insulating effect of the air would increase the conductive heat transfer.  By giving a really high estimate on conduction, I think it does a pretty convincing job showing that even any natural convection would still not be sufficient to dominate over the radiant heat transfer here.